# What RT patch to use for a specific linux kernel version

Tags: kernel, patch, real-time

Running the `$uname -r` command on my embedded device reveals my kernel to be `4.14.73-ltsi` (it is a custom Linux kernel built for an embedded device).

Now I intend to install the real time (RT) patch for this kernel version.  However, on the official [webpage](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/rt/) I don't see a patch specific for kernel version 4.14.73. The nearest ones I see are `patch-4.14.87-rt49.patch.xz` and `patches-4.14.63-rt43.tar.xz`.

Which of these two patches would be most compatible with my Linux kernel version (4.14.73-ltsi) ?

Answer (score 1):

I would try applying the latest patch for 4.14, i.e. https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/rt/4.14/patches-4.14.186-rt86.tar.gz - if it applies cleanly it should work.

If it doesn't please try applying earlier patches from the `older` subdirectory.

Answer (score 1):

Kernel version **4.14** is currently in *Long Term Support* state (LTS) which means it is an old version (or better not the latest stable release), thus no more new feature added **but** it is, and will be for an amount of time, supported/maintained on the security side. This likely is the reason why you will not find the *right* patch-set for your kernel version.

---

Turning to the issue, no one of the two available patch-set will be compatible with your kernel theoretically speaking. *Both will fail.*
Since to apply a patch means **re-compile** the entire kernel, it is not smart for you to try one of these patch-sets on your kernel version. The clever move is to get the right kernel version combined with the right patch-set.

*e.g. staying on 4.14 kernel series for compatibility matters of your embedded device, jump on the **latest** 4.14.186 version*